# Implements neper number (e) with a recursion function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I want to calculate Neper number(*e*) with a recursion function. I have the formula to calculate it:

e = (1/0!) + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) +. . .

I have the code but it won't work properly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double f(double res,int i, int n){

    return (i == n) ? res: res = res + (1 /f(res,i+1,n)*i);
}

int main(){
    cout << f(1,1,2) << endl;
}
```

The result of this code is `2.5` but it should be `2`. Where is the problem?

Comment: What "doesn't work properly" about it?

Comment: The result of this code is't the neper number!!!!

Comment: Soo... what does it print? Have you tried printing each step in f? (Hint: I'm trying to lead you into debugging it yourself, and telling us where you are stuck).

Comment: What number do you get? What other numbers can you get using numbers other than 2,1,100 when calling f? why 2,1,100? Put a little research effort, come on!

Comment: This is the wrong part `1 /f(res,i+1,n)*i`

Comment: The result for n = 2 is 2.5 nut it should be 2 the result for 3 is 2.333 but it should be 2.5 and etc...

Comment: @PhamTrung So do you have any suggestion that can help me to solve it

Comment: Do you want to think? I just show you the problem, what is the formula for n!?

Comment: I know the formula for n! and I can implement it but I think the problem comes up when I want to add it to res

Comment: So tell me if f(res, i + 1,n) *i return i! or not? so your function `f` return both Neper number and factorial of n? Ridiculous!

Comment: yes I think it return i!!!!!! but my f return the sum of 1/i! and this is the neper number

Comment: Why don't you try to print what is f(res, i + 1,n) *i  first?

Comment: the point is you are mixing 2 different things, and trying to calculate e as if it were a continuous funcion, which is not. you need something like `return (i == n) ? res: res + (1 /factorial(i));` where `factorial(int i)` is an appropriate function calculating i!

Comment: @dirluca I see your point but I don't want to use another function like factorial I want to calculate factorial(i) with f function and yes I think  f(res, i + 1,n) *i this is't return i! and here is my problem!!! thanks if you have any suggestion to calculate factorial(i) just with f function It would be grateful.

Comment: Just add `1/i!` as a parameter to `f` and it can easily compute `1/(i+1)!`. Make sure you use a double to store it, because an integer will overflow too quickly.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck or just i! in the parameter, nice idea :)

Comment: Yes it's easy to add i! as parameter to f but it's not my purpose I want to calculate i! inside f and reverse it then sum it with res and calculate the neper number

Comment: Tell me again why you're passing `res` ? It doesn't seem like its needed (and if you dual-purpose the recursive function, `i` is only needed for a flag-var). So I don't see what the problem is ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I need res because I need the addition of 1/i! how can I calculate the neper number without the addition of 1/i so I have to use res

Comment: By using the one thing recursion gives you to do it. the return value on the stack. hold on....

Comment: It's called the Euler number, not the Neper number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure what you want `res` for. In fact, if I got creative with the sign of `n` this doesn't need `i` either.

```
double f(int i, int n)
{
    return (i == 0) ? ((n <= 1) ? 1 : n * f(0,n-1))
        : ((n < 1) ? 1 : 1/f(0, n) + f(i,n-1));
}

int main()
{
    for (int n=1; n<16; ++n)
        std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << f(1,n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2
2.5
2.666666666666667
2.708333333333333
2.716666666666666
2.718055555555555
2.718253968253968
2.71827876984127
2.718281525573192
2.718281801146385
2.718281826198493
2.718281828286169
2.718281828446759
2.71828182845823
2.718281828458995
```

---

This was what I meant about toying with the sign for `n` to eliminate i as well:

```
double f(int n)
{
    return (n < 0) ? ((n == -1) ? 1 : -n * f(n+1))
        : ((n < 1) ? 1 : 1/f(-n) + f(n-1));
}
```

The results are the same. In both cases the function is defined to dual-purpose it recursive algorithm. When asked to, it computes 1/n!, otherwise it computes the running sum + the next number down (which is 1/(n-1)!, etc...)

Comment: This is an answer, thanks to WhozCraig. @DanialV: from a coding point of view having a function doing two very different things (Neper number and factorial) depending on the value of one of the parameters is bad, bad, bad. I do not know why you do not want two different functions, could be a perfectly sensible reason I can't think of, but watch out what you are doing

Comment: @dirluca I utterly concur. I can't think of a good reason to do single-function either (save for saying "because I can"), but the OP was pretty set on it for some reason. dual-purposing was the first thing that came to mind, but IRL no way would I do it this way. The latter snippet is especially dreadful, don't you think =) ?

Comment: As I said I perfectly like the witty answer, it's the question that puzzles me a bit :-)

Comment: WhozCraig Thanks.Your answer was perfect and @dirluca the reason I said I wanted to calculate it just with one function is that why we should use two function when we can do it perfectly with one function!!!

Comment: As you like @DanialV, but pushing it as far as paradox you could say then that main() is enough for everything and all this OOP is just fuss. Having different functions for different uses makes code readable and maintainable. But I stop it here, this is Q&A site and not theoretical debate site.

Comment: Is this not quite inefficient? So f(0,n) resp. f(-n) computes the factorial, for every term the full product from new, and f(i,n) then the sum over the reciprocals of those factorials. This makes n^2/2 multiplications and divisions for a task that should require only n divisions.

Comment: @LutzL oh its dreadfully *inefficient*. I completely like (and up voted) *your* answer. I think it would make for a much nicer algorithm. This was a verbatim translations of the equation to a single (horrid) recursive function. I honestly expected nothing besides a couple up-votes, and was certain you answer would be eventually selected. Frankly I'm shocked it wasn't. As I said, I up ticked it. Others honestly should too.

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution as some kind of riddle, the challenge to put everything into one recursive function with minimal interface. And I think it was selected because it was first and answered the question.

Comment: @LutzL Your probably right regarding selection. Your answer would make a much nicer function, and perhaps the assignment was intended on doing what you did (factoring). Hard saying. Anyway, nice work thinking one step outside the box. I hope more people notice it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The idea is similar to the Horner scheme, so not that original. Additionally, it is expanded upon in one paper by [D. J. Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/arith.html) on "multidigit multiplication for mathematicians" or a similar paper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to Napier, the inventor of the logarithm.

To compute 1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+...+1/n! recursively and efficiently, you can refactor it as 2+1/2*(1+1/3*(1+...1/n))) to obtain the recursive definition

```
h(k,n)=(k==n)?1.0/n:(1.0+h(k+1,n)/k)
f(n)=1+h(2,n)
```

---

You will get faster convergence by using the properties of the exponential function, for instance that e=exp(1/8)^8, also known as the strategy of halving-and-squaring.