# Calculate e in Python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x

What would the easiest way to represent the following equation be?

[image]

Just to clarify, my question is asking for some code that calculates the answer to the equation.

There are two problems with this:

1. The summation warrants an infinite loop which is impossible to get an answer from
2. I hoping for a long, detailed answer (maybe to 40 digits or so).

Comment: What is the question? How to calculate it (off-topic here, try http://math.stackexchange.com)? How to implement the calculation in Python (you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23216920/3001761) useful)? If you just want to *use* `e`, it's in `math`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to calculate it since I can't get an answer from an infinite loop

Comment: Then please edit your question to be more specific. I think it may duplicate the first part of the question I just linked to.

Comment: Why isn't the TEX working? It worked in preview..

Comment: there is no tex support on SO

Comment: Same question with emphasis on recursive implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21875714/3088138

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious solution would be

```
import math

def e(n=10):
    return sum(1 / float(math.factorial(i)) for i in range(n))
```

but it loses precision around n=20 (the error as compared to math.e is around 10^-16)

40-digits precision might be a challenge, and might require arbitrary precision arithmetic

I do not really see the point to have such precise "e" value since you won't be able to perform any calculations with such precision (if you do **anything** to it, you will lose that precision, unless you do everything in some arbitrary precision arithmetic).

Comment: It is absolutely unnecessary to compute the factorial. Just update the terms of the series by the quotient between them. For better accuracy, start with the smallest term. For instance, the five-term partial sum should be evaluated as 2+1/2*(1+1/3*(1+1/4)). This of course only gives an observable difference for a large number of terms. And does not lend itself to a map-reduce pattern, but then there is always a tradeoff between accuracy and convenience.

Comment: Great! BTW you can use Decimal to accomplish a better precision - `print(sum(Decimal(1) / Decimal(math.factorial(i)) for i in range(100)))`

Answer (score 8):

If you need more precision, you could try to use `Fraction`:

```
from fractions import Fraction # use rational numbers, they are more precise than floats
e = Fraction(0)
f = Fraction(1)
n = Fraction(1)
while True:
    d = Fraction(1) / f # this ...
    if d < Fraction(1, 10**40): # don't continue if the advancement is too small
        break
    e += d # ... and this are the formula you wrote for "e"
    f *= n # calculate factorial incrementally, faster than calling "factorial()" all the time
    n += Fraction(1) # we will use this for calculating the next factorial
print(float(e))
```

or `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 40 # set the precision to 40 places
e = Decimal(0)
f = Decimal(1)
n = Decimal(1)
while True:
    olde = e
    e += Decimal(1) / f
    if e == olde: # if there was no change in the 40 places, stop.
        break
    f *= n
    n += Decimal(1)
print(float(e))
```

So here is `e` in 1000 places:

2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127736178215424999229576351482208269895193668033182528869398496465105820939239829488793320362509443117301238197068416140397019837679320683282376464804295311802328782509819455815301756717361332069811250996181881593041690351598888519345807273866738589422879228499892086805825749279610484198444363463244968487560233624827041978623209002160990235304369941849146314093431738143640546253152096183690888707016768396424378140592714563549061303107208510383750510115747704171898610687396965521267154688957035044

To see more clearly what it does, here is its simplified version:

```
e = f = 1.0
for i in range(2, 16):
    e += 1.0 / f
    f *= i
print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

To produce a similar result to [my answer from a question on approximating `pi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216920/3001761):

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(f):
    """Store and retrive previous results of the decorated function f."""
    cache = {}
    @wraps(f)
    def func(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return func

@memoize
def fact(n):
    """Recursively calculates n!."""
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)

def inverse_fact_n(start_n=0):
    """Generator producing the infinite series 1/n!."""
    numerator = 1.0
    denominator = start_n
    while True:
        yield numerator / fact(denominator)
        denominator += 1

def approximate_e(steps=None, tolerance=None):
    """Calculate an approximation of e from summation of 1/n!."""
    if steps is None and tolerance is None:
        raise ValueError("Must supply one of steps or tolerance.")
    series = inverse_fact_n()
    if steps is not None: # stepwise method
        return sum(next(series) for _ in range(steps))
    output = 0 # tolerance method
    term = next(series)
    while abs(term) > tolerance: 
        output += term
        term = next(series)
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from math import e
    print("math.e:\t\t{0:.20f}.".format(e))
    stepwise = approximate_e(steps=100)
    print("Stepwise:\t{0:.20f}.".format(stepwise))
    tolerated = approximate_e(tolerance=0.0000000001)
    print("Tolerated:\t{0:.20f}.".format(tolerated))
```

The function `approximate_e` allows you to specify either:

1. A number of `steps` ("I want it to take this long"); or
2. A desired `tolerance` ("I want it to be this accurate").

There is some relatively advanced Python around this (e.g. the memoizing decorator function and the generator function to produce the series), but you can just focus on the main function, where `next(series)` gives you the next term of the summation.

This gives me the output:

```
math.e:     2.71828182845904509080.
Stepwise:   2.71828182845904553488.
Tolerated:  2.71828182844675936281.
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way is to use the properties of the exponential function.

```
exp(x)=(exp(x/N))^N
```

Thus you compute x=exp(2^(-n)) with 2n bits more precision than required in the final result, and compute e by squaring the result n times.

For small numbers x, the error of truncating the series for exp(x) at the term with power m-1 is smaller than two times the next term with power m.

To summarize, to compute e with a precision/accuracy of d bit, you select some medium large n and select m such that

```
2^(1-mn)/m! is smaller than 2^(-d-2n)
```

This determination of m can also be done dynamically (using Decimal as in the answer of user22698)

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


def eulernumber(d):
    dd=d
    n=4
    while dd > 1:
        dd /= 8
        n += 1
    getcontext().prec = d+n
    x = Decimal(1)/Decimal(1 << n)
    eps = Decimal(1)/Decimal(1 << (1 + (10*d)/3 ))
    term = x
    expsum = Decimal(1) + x
    m = 2
    while term > eps:
        term *= x / Decimal(m)
        m += 1
        expsum += term
    for k in range(n):
        expsum *= expsum
    getcontext().prec = d
    expsum += Decimal(0)
    return expsum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for k in range(1,6):
        print(k,eulernumber(4*k))

    for k in range(10,13):
        print(k,eulernumber(4*k))
```

with output

```
( 1, Decimal('2.718'))
( 2, Decimal('2.7182818'))
( 3, Decimal('2.71828182846'))
( 4, Decimal('2.718281828459045'))
( 5, Decimal('2.7182818284590452354'))
(10, Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757'))
(11, Decimal('2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572471'))
(12, Decimal('2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709370'))
```

See the (unix/posix) bc math library for a more professional implementation of this idea, also for the logarithm and trig functions. The code of the exponential function is even given as example in the man page.